# How can I track xamarin.mac app unhandled exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I want to get crash reports for unhandled exception in my xamarin mac application like hockey app used for tracking exceptions for android and ios apps. I have search a lot but not get any apps for tracking unhandled exception. Please suggest any app for tracking exceptions in xamarin.mac. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Task Exceptions often go unobserved (i.e., any exception that occurs in a non-awaited Task.Run()). You can catch them by putting this in your AppDelegate's DidFinishLaunching override:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += 
TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;

void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, 
UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("**Unobserved Exception**");
    System.Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest implementing it on your own. The Main.cs file acts as the main entry point to a Xamarin Mac application. It contains a static `Main` method that creates a new Xamarin.Mac application instance:

```
using AppKit;

namespace Test
{
    static class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NSApplication.Init();
            NSApplication.Main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

You can try to set an handler here (after `NSApplication.Init();`:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException 
    += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

string a = null;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.Length);
```

The last two lines of course force a null pointer exception.

One piece is missing:

```
private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("oh no");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your valuable support. I have tried fallowing code as your given sample working great but didn't catch any unhandled exceptions all over the application. In my app after navigating few pages, application crashed but above code didn't catch that unhandled exception.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that my suggestion did not work as expected. According to the docs, `CurrentDomain` gets the application domain for the current Thread. Maybe the code that did not raise the handler was executed in another thread? Unfortunately I have no other ideas.

Comment: Crashes not caught by this solution are possibly happening on the Core Graphics Drawing layer

Comment: Okay. Thank you Thomas

Comment: Stepheaw is any another idea for catching this type of exceptions?.